# Running launchd agent not preventing macbook from sleeping

Tags: launchd

I have an agent/daemon that runs a backup script (I use [restic](https://restic.net/)) at 4:05am on a StartCalendarInterval. My understanding is that if a launchd agent is running, that should prevent osx from sleeping. Is that wrong?

I can see that my script partially worked as a snapshot was created in the repository, but when I went to check the snapshot, the repo had a lock on it which indicates to me something happened mid-run.

Here is my plist file for the agent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>backup.restic.username</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/Users/username/Documents/scripts/backup.sh</string>
                </array>
                <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Minute</key>
                        <integer>5</integer>
                        <key>Hour</key>
                        <integer>4</integer>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Is there something I can add there to prevent sleeping? I will say the macbook wasn't plugged in and was at 35% battery when I woke up.

Comment: Most probably not related to the issue, but is it a copy/paste issue or does your plist really contain the first two lines twice?

Comment: As for the question as such: Check out `man caffeinate` and a bunch of questions/answers on this site regarding its use and constraints.

Comment: @nohillside, copy/paste issue. Sorry! A brief look and caffeinate appears to be what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@nohillside gave me what to lookup. Updated to use caffeinate to prevent disk and system from sleeping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>backup.restic.username</string>
                <key>Program</key>
                <string>/usr/bin/caffeinate</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>-im</string>
                        <string>/Users/username/Documents/scripts/backup.sh</string>
                </array>
                <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Minute</key>
                        <integer>5</integer>
                        <key>Hour</key>
                        <integer>4</integer>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: When using `ProgramArguments` the first string is actually assigned to `$0` during execution (so should be the name of the program again).

Comment: I've tested this a few times with `launchctl start backup.restic.username` and it works as intended. I don't see any errors in `/var/log/system.log` as well. Could it be a change in launchd versions? Based on my googling, they've changed a lot in recent years :D. Edit: It looks like you are correct UNLESS you also use the key `Program`.